# How to remove only one inline <style> from Wordpress head

Tags: php, css, wordpress, inline

I'm designing a Wordpress site that's not yet live. There is a block of inline css in the head of the home page that needs to go. I'm not sure where it's being generated from but the I've modified the css since and the inline css isn't updating to match it.

I've tried overruling it by using !important in my custom.css.

I've tried adding my style sheet just above the  so it loads last.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://mywebsite/wpnew/wp-content/themes/mytheme/custom.css?counter=1491147962' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I've tried adding this to my functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'customcss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.css', array(), time() );
```

I've deleted the widget that the css belongs to thinking the page might render without the inline css since the widget was gone but it's still there.

I'm at a loss. I'm not a programmer and not entirely comfortable with php. I found a plugin that strips all inline tags but I only want to get rid of this one block of css.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Finally your style is inline or external? If it's inline, find it in your `<head>`. If it's external, find where it's been called, it depends on your theme, it could be in a file like `script.php` or `scripts.php` or somewhere else. You should dig up your theme.

Comment: make jsfiddle with your webpage and add the link in your question. One option is to use javascript to find that script tag and eliminate it

Comment: @ata The style was originally in my custom.css -- I'm not sure why Wordpress or the theme rendered it inline. If it comes from the theme, maybe the developer can tell me how it's generated.

Comment: @repzero I'll have to google what jsfiddle means and how to make one -- I'm new to this.

Comment: @Joanne it is a website where you sign up for free. You create a new fiddle, add your html,css and javascript codes inside, and click 'run' to see how your webpage looks. You save your fiddle and insert the link to your new fiddle in your question so we can view it.... link here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @repzero Thank you. I found the web site and took a quick tutorial. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used WordPress but installed it on my localhost and tried to modify the (e.g.) h1 tag with `class="site-title"` on the default template.
Just search on the folder for 'site-title' and found the header.php according to the activated template or your custom template.

Some code is generated by php and then sent to user so maybe to try to find a class that hasn't the same name in your php files than you see in your html received files. Try to find class/id in some tags near the one you want to change.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

wp_enqueue_style takes 5 parameter

$handle
(string) (Required) Name of the stylesheet. Should be unique.

$src
(string) (Optional) Full URL of the stylesheet, or path of the stylesheet relative to the WordPress root directory.
Default value: ''

$deps
(array) (Optional) An array of registered stylesheet handles this stylesheet depends on.
Default value: array()
$ver
(string|bool|null) (Optional) String specifying stylesheet version number, if it has one, which is added to the URL as a query string for cache busting purposes. If version is set to false, a version number is automatically added equal to current installed WordPress version. If set to null, no version is added.

Default value: false
$media
(string) (Optional) The media for which this stylesheet has been defined. Accepts media types like 'all', 'print' and 'screen', or media queries like '(orientation: portrait)' and '(max-width: 640px)'.
Default value: 'all'

You can change your code in function.php file

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'mycustom_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.css', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

it will be work. check that you have only one custom.css file in your theme root .

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give me such detailed information. It's still a little scary for me to play around with the php files. Isn't there just an easy way to stop wordpress from sticking the custom css on the page? I just want to turn that feature off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **wp_dequeue_style**  and **wp_deregister_style**.

If you are going to view source, you can see the WP_HEAD generate link style like below:

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' id='mystyle-css'  href='www.your_domain.com/css.style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Now, if you want to remove this line, just go to your functions.php and include the code below:

```
function dequeue_unnecessary_styles_vxt() {
    $styles = array('mystyle'); //store here all the CSS you want to remove
    foreach ($styles as $key => $value) {
        wp_dequeue_style( $value );
        wp_deregister_style( $value );
    }      
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'dequeue_unnecessary_styles_vxt' );
```

I have edited the code above so you can dynamically remove all css styles you want to remove. Note that, from css link style, there is an id called, **mystyle-css** this is how you will track the css in your custom functions.php. Add the ID (without -css) insde the $styles.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to stop Wordpress from embedding the custom.css not from accessing it. Does this stop Wordpress from linking to the custom.css completely?

Comment: where did you add the custom.css? is it inside your header.php or functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your header file, probably in the `<head>` you will find

```
<?php echo get_template_part('customcss'); ?>
```

And also there is `customcss.php` in your theme folder. But you should be aware this is the styles you assign in your WordPress Dashboard and deleting it, won't be as happy ever after as you think. You can delete the code or change `customcss.php`. If it is not as that, look for some phrase of php that `echo` your CSS file.

Comment: Is there a plugin that stops Wordpress from embedding (am I using the right word?) or rendering the custom css inline? I'm not comfortable playing around with the php.

Comment: @Joanne I don't know. If there would be, probably they could work with `wp_equeue_style` and `wp_register_style`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider executing the hook with low preference like 100 or above.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    //conditional tags or check function
        wp_dequeue_style( 'inline-style-id' );
    }
}, 100 ); //important to pass it with low preference.
```